# error '_' is not defined no-undef

Tags: lodash, eslint

I use eslint to check my code ,and a error happen -- "error '_' is not defined no-undef".

I write the code like this:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",//jquery
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    _:"lodash"//lodash
})
```

and get .eslintrc.js, part of it like this:

```
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jquery":true,
},
```

before I add the jquery into ,it happen an error -- "error '_' is not defined no-undef".
However, when I add lodash into ,just like that "'lodash':true".It doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ESLint doesn't understand lodash library.
you need to add a global section in your config.

"globals": {
    "_": true
  },

Comment: Am getting a similar error in react. Where exactly do i place this? @DaNesh

Comment: @Phares  Here: https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard/blob/master/eslintrc.json you can see a sample config file with a globals section.

Comment: This might help someone: if you using PhpStorm vue configuration, add 
`"globals": { "_": true },` to package.json `"eslintConfig"` section.
If you see `Lodash ReferenceError: _ is not defined`, add `import _ from 'lodash';` to your script

Comment: This does not work. Perhaps I'm adding it in a wrong file, or wrong section. If sure that this does in fact work, please specify more clearly where to add this configuration item.

Comment: @svenema please check here. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals