# " '_' is not defined no-undef" error when redirecting to another webpage with JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, routes, eslint

That error doesn't show up when I open the html page manually but it does when I try to connect it to a different .js file using

```
    import main from './Components/Shopping/function';
```

and

```
    <Route path="/Shopping">
        <main />
    </Route>
```

before running it with nodemon app and npm start.

Also, when I enclose all the code in function.js in a function using

```
var main = () => {
    //code
}

export default main;
```

for the routing, the code in function.js doesn't work when I manually open the HTML file that uses it.

**Edit:** Apparently all it needed was `npm install underscore` in the cmd in the directory with function.js, and `const _ = require("underscore");` in function.js. But even though there are no errors, it won't load the webpage. It's just blank, apart from a navigation bar (But the URL does change to (url)/Shopping). And the HTML page opened manually still can't use the code from function.js.

Comment: Clearly you're using more than "just Javascript" - there seems to be some framework or another involved.  In any case: look here: [error '\_' is not defined no-undef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317154/error-is-not-defined-no-undef)

Comment: That might help but I'm not sure where it's supposed to be added in my files

Comment: So what framework(s) *are* you using?  ReactJS?  That's key to understanding the problem.  And probably the reason you're using "npm" at all...

Comment: Node, React, and Express

Comment: OK: your next step is to debug the HTTP requests/responses, e.g. using the "network" tab in [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).  I suspect you'll find one or another parts of your ReactJS build aren't being served correctly.  ALSO: If you're not already, please consider using an IDE, like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and see if I can find something